# Centering a navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I'm in the process of learning css and js, and I was looking at this nice looking navigation bar

http://codepen.io/atelierbram/pen/gCqDy

however, when I set it up on a test website I cannot get the navigation bar to center. `text-align` doesn't do anything, setting `margin:auto;` seems to have no effect either. What's going on in this that I can't center the navigation bar by normal means?

Comment: Floated. Plus some extra characters to add the comment.

Answer (score 0):

In that example, `#fancy-nav` is actually floated to the right with a width of 50%.  It *appears* to be centered, but it's not a traditional method for centering.

To use the `margin:auto` method, you'll need to give your HTML element some width, for example:

```
#nav-wrap {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Of course, this simple example eliminates the dynamic sizing of the container, so it's really not all that useful if you're looking for a dynamic layout.  There are plenty of resources available that talk about dynamically centering dynamic divs.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `#fancy-nav` style to `margin` it for the middle position by using `margin:0 auto` and remove the `float:right` property

```
#fancy-nav { 
    margin:0 auto;
    position: relative; 
  width: 50%;
}
```

Check it [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rjsuo)

Answer (score 0):

add this css

```
#fancy-nav{  
   display: table;
   margin: 0 auto;
   position: relative;
}
```

Comment: hi, thank you this worked for me. However, why? And I read somewhere that you no longer should use display:table; to style.